# Problems When I change my PHP version to 7.2(Error 0 Using $this when not in object context )

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, fatal-error, php7, hosting

I have my website in production now, The site works very good with PHP 5.6 and 7.0 but When I try to change the PHP version to 7.2 the website doesn't work. It shows me an error message like this: [image]

I'm using the Template BigEasy Version 1.0
and my Joomla version is 3.9.0

Do you know guys what could it be the cause of this error?
This is the site -> https://www.wpz-schuepfheim.ch/ you can check it and watch the error.

Comment: you'll need a stacktrace to find the location of the code that's causing the problem.  Often the template will give you one if you turn on debug in global config.

Comment: Des that error goes off if you change the template.

Comment: It's the same (or very similar) problem as it was here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23665/upgrade-php-to-7-2-cause-error about a week ago. The OP disappeared, so we probably will never know what was the real reason of the error in that case, since he/she was not answering my question. The full stack-trace of the error should be uploaded here. The earlier similar error is derived from a wrong asset call basically by an outdated content plugin (as far as i traced it back).

Comment: @[Gillian](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/13040/gillian) would like to know: "Have you made sure that mbstring is enabled in the PHP extensions selector?"

Answer (score -1):

Have you made sure that mbstring is enabled in the PHP extensions selector? When you change from an earlier version it doesn't remember your previous selections; you have to add them again. (Sorry, can't add a 'comment' as I don't have a 50+ reputation)

Comment: Yes, it is a drag that you can't comment until you have earned the privilege.  For the time being, please do not try to circumvent this rule by asking for clarity via an answer.  Please seek out questions to answer which do not require any clarification.  There are thousands of other questions that are available if you would like to share your knowledge with this community.